# Find IP of VM running KVM

Tags: ip, linux-kvm

How can I find the IP of the VM on KVM(using Nmap)? If not,are there any functions in Libvirt to do that?

Comment: Answer:
After a day's worth of trying nmap/ifconfig/iptables, I chanced to stumble upon this - http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/tip-find-the-ip-address-of-a-virtual-machine/. epic link.

Comment: Two virsh commands: domifaddr and net-dhcp-leases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long hours of getting my hands dirty, I chanced to stumble upon [this](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/tip-find-the-ip-address-of-a-virtual-machine/) Epic link.

1. Get the MAC address of the VM from the config file of the VM(since
   I'm using KVM, I queried the .xml file for the MAC address).
2. Then use arp -a and get all the the MAC addresses and the Address of the interfaces and store it in a file
3. Query the file for the MAC address of VM from step 1.

Comment: Could you describe how this solved your problem? What did you do exactly?

Comment: @Simon Sheehan-
Here's how I did it-
1. get the MAC address of the VM from the config file of the VM(since I'm using KVM, I queried the .xml file for the MAC address).
2. Then use arp -a and get all the the MAC addresses and the Address of the interfaces and store it in a file
3.query the file for the MAC address of VM from step 1.

Comment: Great, I added that to your answer

Answer (score 4):

Fast and dirty example for KVM on Centos 63 x86_64. Short ping in background to all possible IP addresses that the VMs may have in this segment

```
for i in {1..249}
 do
  ping -c 1 -n -q -r  -t 1 -s 1  -W 1   192.168.100.$i > /dev/null &
done
```

Extract the names and MAC addresses  of the VMs via virsh  and extract IP from ARP table

```
for name in `virsh list | grep running | awk '{ print $2 }'`
do
  printf  "\n$name\n "
  arp -e | grep "`virsh dumpxml  $name | grep "mac address"|sed "s/.*'\(.*\)'.*/\1/g"`" | 
  awk '{ printf  $1 ;  printf  " "  ; printf  $3 }'
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a bash script to do this but to also filter for machines with the name "swarm" in them.  You could remove the filter or change it as needed. (remove `| grep "swarm"`)  You could use this as the full script or copy paste the one liner from it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# we make assumption that the VM's we want have the word swarm in their name.  Edit for different name or to get all unfiltered names
for i in $(virsh list | grep "swarm" | awk '{print $2;}' ); do virsh domifaddr $i | sed 3q | sed '$!d' |awk '{print $4}'  ; done;
```

The constituent parts are virsh commands, `virsh list` to get a list of all VM's, and then in a for loop calling `domifaddr <VM NAME>` to get the ip addr of it.  All the rest is to filter out the text to only the IP address one per line. I wrote/ran this in Ubuntu KVM server 15.10

Answer (score 1):

When started with `qemu-kvm` and the `--nographic` option, you can use `ctrl-a` `c` to get the qemu monitor (some  kind of shell to monitor and control VMs).

The command `info network` will give network connection info, including MAC address.
The command `info usernet` shows bridge information: e.g. how a guest port is mapped to a host port. This information often includes the guest ip.

### Example

Start vm with some tcp port forwarding:

```
qemu-kvm -cpu host -m 1024 -hda ~/myvm.qcow -net user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22 -net nic -nographic
```

after `ctrl-a` `c` the commands `info network` and `info usernet` give

```
(qemu) info network
hub 0
 \ hub0port1: e1000.0: index=0,type=nic,model=e1000,macaddr=58:44:00:22:11:
 \ hub0port0: user.0: index=0,type=user,net=10.0.2.0,restrict=off
(qemu) info usernet
VLAN 0 (user.0):
  Protocol[State]    FD  Source Address  Port   Dest. Address  Port RecvQ S
  TCP[HOST_FORWARD]  13               * 10022       10.0.2.15    22     0
```

Reference: [QEMU-doc](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html#Commands) at wiki.qemu.org.

Answer (score 0):

Using virt-cat command, you can query all files on a VM. For example, the dhcp lease file:

virt-cat -d your_domain /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `get-vm-ip` script (which you can download from https://github.com/earlruby/create-vm/blob/master/get-vm-ip) which uses this to get the IP:

```
HOSTNAME=[your vm name]
MAC=$(virsh domiflist $HOSTNAME | awk '{ print $5 }' | tail -2 | head -1)
arp -a | grep $MAC | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[()]//g'
```

The virsh command gets the MAC address, the last line finds the IP address using `arp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# iterate over all running kvm vms
for i in $(virsh list | grep running | awk '{print $2}'); do virsh domifaddr  $i; done
 Name       MAC address          Protocol     Address
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 vnet2      52:54:00:54:XX:XX    ipv4         192.168.122.148/24
```

if the vms have dhcp assigned addresses of the network "default"

```
virsh net-start default
virsh net-autostart default

virsh net-dhcp-leases default

 Expiry Time           MAC address         Protocol   IP address           Hostname    Client ID or DUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2024-01-08 13:08:39   52:54:00:15:XX:XX   ipv4       192.168.122.207/24   ubuntu      ff:56:50:4d:...
 2024-01-08 13:42:21   52:54:00:95:XX:XX   ipv4       192.168.122.162/24   debian12    ff:00:95:9d:6e:...
 2024-01-08 13:40:09   52:54:00:aa:XX:XX   ipv4       192.168.122.249/24   vmname   -
```

alternatively: arp scan local network

```
netdiscover
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [qemu guest agent](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/interop/qemu-ga.html) installed on the VM, you can use `virsh's` `domifaddr` command for that:

```sh
wouter@hypervisor:~$ virsh -c qemu:///system domifaddr myvmname
 Name       MAC address          Protocol     Address
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 vnet4      52:54:00:5c:5b:38    ipv4         192.168.122.217/24

wouter@hypervisor:~$
```